# How to get the HTML tag of some text on a page using selenium

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-rc

```
<div class="searchSummary floatL">
<span>18</span>
results for "gloves"
</div>
```

How could i get the tag for '18' using selenium. I am looking to retrieve 'span'.

is that possible and how using selenium and css?
thanks

Comment: use xpath, it could be easily done by using: //div[@class='searchSummary floatL']span

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium with Java, given you have a WebDriver driver, try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.searchSummary.floatL span")).getTagName();
```

If you wish to make it more dynamic (if you want to find the tag name of a span containing a particular string) use XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='searchSummary floatL']/*[contains(.,'18')]")).getTagName();
```